Recommendation: matrix factorization vs neural network training
In the case of collaborative filtering, say we have a matrix of item-item (could also be user-item) interactions.

In the "matrix factorization" approach, we use algorithms such as SVD or ALS to get the item embeddings matrices.

But we can also simply implement it using two embedding layers in pytorch, and optimise using for example stochastic gradient descent. In the end, we also get item embedding matrices See code example https://github.com/eugeneyan/recsys-nlp-graph/blob/master/src/ml/mf.py


I'm a bit confused as to why we have two seemingly different algorithm to solve the same thing:

matrix factorization with ALS or SVD on one hand
neural network training with with SGD on the other

Some articles use one approach, other use the other, without never mentioning how they are related.
My question is: are those 2 approaches the same? Is there a way to 'reduce' one approach to the other? In practice, is one approach superior to the other?
